# Echo doesn't show first row made

Tags: php, row, echo

I have this problem with my task system,

whenever a new member makes his first task, it doesn't show up. Only the ones made after the first one.

```
    <?php

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['member_id']."' ORDER by id ASC");
            if (!$sql) {
                die ('invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

                 $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {    

?>
```

After that I just echo out all of the content (tasks). each row under eachother. But the first task made just doesn't show up. It remains hidden.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: i can't imagine what you mean. please post some sourcecode and comment it, so we can understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

this is too much. delete it. it fetches the first line, so the while loop can't get the first line.

additionally, i wouldn't use `mysql_fetch_array` in the while, use mysql_fetch_assoc to use an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

The call $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); is fetching the first row, you don't need that line. What is happening is that that line fetches the first row, and updates $sql (which is the resultset resource) to point to the second row,  then when you call  mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) it starts from the second row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it now